# White image saved with stbi_write_bmp has black columns. Why?

Tags: c, image, for-loop, image-processing, stb-image

I created a white image with this code:

```
#include "stb_image/stb_image.h"
#include "stb_image/stb_image_write.h"

int main(void){
    int width = 1440;
    int height = 1080;
    int j, l;
    float *img_slopes = (float *)malloc(width * height * sizeof(float));
    for (l = 0; l < width; l++) {
        for (j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            *(img_slopes + j * width + l) = 255;
        }
    }
    stbi_write_bmp("answer_blank.bmp", width, height, 1, img_slopes);
}
```

Those cycles should scroll through each and every pixel. But the output is:

[png screen-capture of the answer_blank.bmp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzyuw.png)

Why is that? Why do I have black columns? What exactly is happening here?

If it's not clear enough from the print-screen, every other column is black.

Comment: Last time I checked, bmp files did not use `float` values.

Comment: @Gerhardh you're right. It should be unsigned char

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user @Gerhadh kindly [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76154026/white-image-saved-with-stbi-write-bmp-has-black-columns-why?noredirect=1#comment134300004_76154026), the .bmp don't use `float` vales. It should be an `unsigned char` matrix instead.